# Empty password field in /etc/passwd

Tags: authentication, linux

I am reversing a firmware update and found a empty password field in `/etc/passwd`

```
root::0:0:root:/:/bin/sh
otheruser:x:0:0:otheruser:/bin/false
```

Do I need a password to login as root?

I found out, that the x in the password field indicates that the hash is written in `/etc/shadow`, were a * indicates that the password is empty.
The `/etc/shadow` is not included in the firmware update, so i don't know the content.

Comment: About the root user, it is normally not to have password in /etc/shadow because you want to use SUDO privileges instead of root user. Keep it disabled from remote logins and even local access. The only way you should access to root privileges is thru sudo.

Comment: If you want to permit login you would set the shell to /bin/false, rigth? The question is if the missing x means that a blanc password is used

Comment: No, the shell /bin/false returns false immediately after login so you'll get logged out automatically. About the password, you're right about the blank password, currently your root user doesn't have any password assigned. You could set a ! to block the account for example

Comment: thanks, so maybe i can get a root-shell on the device :)

Comment: However, this does not mean that SSH will allow root to log in without a password.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An empty password field means the `root` account can be accessed without any password.

An `*` or `!` means the account don't have a password and no password will access the account. An `x` means the password is on `/etc/shadow`.